# React-Native Expo app suddenly will not run because of Invariant Violation: 'main' has not been registered

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Im using expo to build a react native app, and it has been working totally fine for days now. However, out of no where, it started to give me an Invariant Violation: 'main' has not been registered issue, and preventing me from building the app. Here is a photo.[Error as well as AppEntry.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q91Ik.jpg)

Also, I am relatively new to expo and react-native in general, so there are some things I don't understand still. I have searched everywhere for an answer, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

### quick solution that worked for me

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder
2. Delete your `yarn.lock` file (if you are using yarn)
3. Run your installs again `npm i` or `yarn` (if you are using yarn)

Answer (score 0):

This worked when had a similar issue after I created a new app. Doing something similar might fix your issue.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.